# How to does phantom handle errors

Tags: cassandra, phantom-dsl

When inserting/updating into Cassandra, or when say the table defintion in the application does not match the table definition in the C* server, how does phantom handle these types of errors?

I see a result set that has wasApplied etc. but nothing about exceptions or errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is catastrophic and the operation couldn't execute you will get back a failed future. One such example is a `scala.concurrent.Future` wrapping an `InvalidQueryException` for instance.

Now there is a great degree of variety to what failure could mean. If you insert partial data that's valid in Cassandra, columns automatically set to `null` even if business wise this doesn't make sense in your application.

The table definition should always match the table definition in the database if you use schema auto-generation via `Database.create` method, so phantom already provides a mechanism for you to do that automatically.